# How to identify which component/Service threw the error , while using a global HTTP Interceptor as an error handler in Angular?

Tags: angular, frontend, angular-http-interceptors

I am using an HTTPInterceptor to handle any error that occurs in the Angular app.Once an error occurs ,it is thrown and handled by this interceptor. However , once an error is thrown towards the interceptor , I want to identify which component or service threw that error.

I expect the following, If main.service.ts is the service where the error occurs , I want to get the name ' main.service.ts ' in my HTTPInterceptor class.

Comment: If you `throw err`, it should output the service in the console trace.

Comment: @Maryannah .console.trace() actually gives the stack trace of the error. However it doesn't contain the Component/Service name that threw the error.

Comment: Yes it gives the trace, and the traces crawls up back to the origin of the error, which goes from the interceptor to the core, going through RxJS & the service.

Comment: @Maryannah    OK yes, got the name on the console.... By any chance do you know anyway I can retrieve it on my angular app ( like retrieve that component name and store it in an angular variable )?

Comment: Hum no, don't think so. You would have to provide your service/component as a context/parameter, which means it can't be implicit, i.e. you have to explicitly write it.

Comment: Bu what would be the end goal there ? Maybe we can find another solution to your issue

Comment: @Maryannah Hmm Ok lets see.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the component that threw the error , however we can identify which method threw the error. 
We need a package called 'extract-stack'

`npm install extract-stack`

then, get the function name as follows. Angular doesn't change the function name even in production mode, so we can catch the method where the error occurred, as -:

`var function_name = extractStack.lines(errors)[0].split('.')[1].split(' ')[0];`